# Subtract mean from a variable by group in bigmemory in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, statistics

I would like to demean the variables from the big.matrix (panel) structure. I tried different methods but the one which works in bigmemory setting is tapply (provided by bigtabulate package). I have the following code to calculate means of variable var1 by groups represented by panel_id

```
data <- read.big.matrix ("data.csv", sep = ",", header=TRUE, type = "double", backingfile = "backing.bin" , descriptor = "data.desc")
xdesc <- dget ("data.desc")
data <- attach.big.matrix(xdesc)

mean_var1=tapply(data[,"var1"], data[,"panel_id"], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Since the length of var1 is different from the one of mean_var1, I cannot simply subtract one from another to demean the variables. Do you have any ideas how to subtract from each observation of var1 its group mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to use the `bigsplit` function and a `for` loop for in-place modification.

```
idx <- bigsplit(data, 1)

for(i in seq(length(idx))){
    data[idx[[i]],2] <- data[idx[[i]],2] - mean_var1[i]
}
```

It appears like you will want the former but if you wanted a subset returned of a reasonable size (i.e. not exceedingly RAM) then you could use `lapply` or even explore some parallelization with `foreach`

```
# use lapply
lapply(seq(length(idx)), function(x) data[idx[[x]],] - mean_var1[[x]])

# use foreach (don't forget to register you backend!!!)
library(foreach)
foreach(iter = seq(length(idx))) %dopar% {
    data[idx[[iter]],2] - mean_var1[iter]
}
```